# iPhone stuck on Apple Logo because of Storage Full, Any solution to delete some data to make it boot or backup data before restore?

Tags: backup, jailbreak, data-recovery, ios

My iPhone 6s Plus (iOS 13.4) was full on memory and when I restarted the phone it stuck on Apple Logo. Unfortunately I have no backup of my device and want my data to be safe and backed up before restoring device. Things I tried : 1. Tried Updating iPhone using IPSW file with Fonepaw, iTunes. Gets stuck on 30% of process (Error Code -1) 2. Tried Backing up the device using Elcomsoft_iOS_Forensic_Toolkit. The tool is unable to detect device in DFU Mode and hence unable to Backup or save Media Files from phone. 3. Tried Flashing using 3uTools, Stuck in between and giving Error code 14. Researched on this code and it is because of the Storage Full. 4. Tried to create IPSW using Make_No_Erase_Ipsw apparently the developer didn't updated the tool and the Error it shows : KeyError : 'RestoreRamDisks'

Status of my device right : It is in Recovery Mode and after several minutes it restarts itself. My last iOS version before phone getting bricked was iOS 13.4

Questions : 1. Is there anyway to access the hard drive and delete a few chuck of data so that it boots again? 2. Is there anyway to backup device before restoring it as restore will erase all the data from device? 3. Lastly, If I restore my device will the hard drive retain some of my data so that I can restore it later and If yes how can I mount the hard drive to use recovery tool and which recovery tool is best to restore the data from phone's drive?

I'm looking for a solution to restore my device without losing data. I'm okay to Jailbreak my device as well If it helps to restore the device without loosing data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even when full, the system should start. Are you sure its not a different problem happening at the same time as you think you filled it up? The flashing may have tipped you past the normal fail safes and you have no option but to erase it entirely.

Comment: If it's valuable data, contact drivesavers.com   Otherwise, you have learned the importance of backup. turn off wifi router.  turn off blue tooth devices. Re-boot ipad.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559